# AngularJs directive that takes user input as string and reformats it to alternate upper lower case. E.g compter becomes CoMpUtEr

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am new to AngularJs and trying hard to find a solution for this. I am just learning directives and have been able to get my directive to work showing a textbox for the user to type into. The logic to change to upper and lower case characters from a string is what I'm puzzled with.

I thought maybe something like:

```
if (inputValue % 2 == 0) {
//have the user input.ToUpperCase()
}
```

E.g if user types in `computer` the textbox would dynamically update as the user types to `CoMpUtEr`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do in this case is to write custom directive. You need to make sure that the model is properly transformed in all cases: through input in the field, as well as when the model changes in code like `$scope.model = 'some'` - then it's supposed to get translated to `SoMe` in the view.

Here is a basic directive I wrote to alternate characters case.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('capitalizeAlternate', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
                
                function formatter(value) {
                    if (value) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                                value = value.substr(0, i) + value[i].toUpperCase() + value.substr(i + 1);
                            }
                        }
                        return value;
                    }
                }
                
                ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                    if (value) {
                        ngModelController.$viewValue = formatter(value);
                        ngModelController.$render(); 
                        return ngModelController.$viewValue;
                    }
                });
    
                ngModelController.$formatters.push(formatter);
            }
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <input capitalize-alternate type="text" ng-model="input" /> {{input}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your input add the handler ng-change="unformatMyText". Then add this funtion to your view, like unformatMyText: function(txt){}. Within the function body add your code. This should do the trick every time.